# How do I create a custom attribute which is affected by runtime variables? (e.g. PrincipalPermissionAttribute)

Tags: c#, .net, attributes

How do I create an attribute which tests a variable each time the method is invoked?

When the `PrincipalPermissionAttribute` is attached to a method (shown below). If the rules specified in the parameters are not met an exception is thrown.

```
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "Admin"]
public void MyMethod()
{
    //Do something if you are an "Admin"
}
```

Basically (in this example), **whenever `MyMethod()` is invoked** the value of `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` is tested and if it is not of the Role "Admin" a `SecurityException` is thrown.

So... how do I mimic this behaviour? I would like a method attribute which 'reacts' to a runtime variable. Most of the attribute examples I've found on the web relate to appending a Display name to a property or something similar.

Comment: There is no magic with `Attribute`s. It is mainly within your `Attribute` class that you will check upon instantiation that the value passed to your attribute constructor is what is expected, otherwise you throw a WhateverException.

Comment: I've tried playing with them, but the attribute constructor code isn't entered when the method is invoked... and the fact that in a lot of places attributes are described as attaching additional meta data to methods and properties etc. which makes me thick they are entered at compile time not runtime, if thats true.. how does their behaviour differ when runtime variables change? Plus you can only pass constants in to attribute constructors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding of .NET attributes seems to be a little muddy.

Attributes are a way of attaching meta-information to classes and assemblies for the purposes of reflection.

**Attributes typically do not contain behaviour. They are just data.**

What you're seeing with `PrincipalPermissionAttribute` is the .NET Runtime security system being invoked. The security process checks for security-related attributes on a method when the method is invoked. The presence of attributes direct the behaviour of the security process.

If you want to have an attribute change the behaviour of your program, you first need something to be actively looking for the attribute.

Comment: That sounds sensible, and all the examples of attribute use I have seen say the same "attaches additional meta data". So... where is this security process running? Is it just ever-present background .Net stuff?  It feels clunky to imagine some process looking for security attributes on every method I invoke.

Comment: This is exactly how .NET's Code Access Security (CAS) works. When invoking a method, the security portion of the runtime checks for metadata and performs security actions. It's an intrinsic part of the managed runtime, which makes it harder to create your own equivalent system.

Answer (score 2):

Use an [AOP framework](http://www.postsharp.com) for this, to inject code when a certain method is hit. You can also do this native via the .NET framework with a [ContextBoundObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.contextboundobject.aspx); which is probably what they've used in the framework.

Comment: +1 for the ContextBoundObject... I haven't come across them before. Interesting.

Comment: Just found this which seems to relate... [Decouple Components by Injecting Custom Services into Your Object's Interception Chain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/cc164165.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking about this wrong.  It's not that the attribute has a changing value, it's that its interpretation by the code that uses the attribute is based on runtime state.  In the example you gave, it is probably the case that the code which checks for that attribute also does the checking of Thread.CurrentPrinciple and takes action based on that.  The attribute does nothing but store a few constant fields.  It's best if you do the same.  Remember also that putting an attribute on a method (or anything else) doesn't magically do anything.  You have to have code that by reflection grabs those attributes and interprets the data in them in some useful and relevant way.  So it's up to your interpreter code, not the attribute.